# How to load url from terminal in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, npm, proxy

When I execute my app, I need to manually enter url in browser and it redirects via proxy to target url.

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var app = express();

app.use(proxy({target: 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world', changeOrigin: true}));
app.listen(5000);
```

I want to get the page details e.g html by loading same from terminal. How can I do that?

What I tried is

```
$node redirectproxy.js  & curl 'http://localhost:5000'
```

but it gives me below error message

> [4] 5728 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000:
>   Connection refused

Comment: acccording to [http-proxy-middleware doc](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) you need to use proxy like this: `app.use('local_path', proxy(...));`

Comment: I already used the same, please check 2nd last loc

Comment: I don't understand, have you tried `app.use("/", proxy({target: 'https://www.google.[...]', changeOrigin: true}));` ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but makes no difference to include it or not

Comment: `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7): Failed to connect() to host or proxy.` Have you checked your firewall ?